# check if date exists and then compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have that join statement in query

```
inner join ( select uas.UserId,  max(uas.[TimeStamp]) as maxDate 
from dbo.UserSt as uas group by uas.UserId ) as tb2
                on tb2.UserId = e.UserId and tb2.maxDate < e.[TimeStamp]
```

How can I first check if `maxDate` exists in `tb2` table and then compare it?

I need that if maxDate doesn't exists in that table take value from `e.[TimeStamp]`

Comment: Can you please post sample schema of both tables

Comment: @TheGameiswar they're tables which have same UserId. another isn't necessary. It's too complex query

Comment: You're more likely to get a satisfactory answer if you can provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Will tb2 return no records, or records with a NULL maxDate when maxDate doesn't exist?  Does your query return 1 or a number of records?  With this kind of context you are more likely to recieve the answer you are  looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
left join ( select uas.UserId,  max(uas.[TimeStamp]) as maxDate 
from dbo.UserSt as uas group by uas.UserId ) as tb2
                on tb2.UserId = e.UserId and 
((tb2.maxDate < e.[TimeStamp] and tb2.maxDate is not null) or 
(e.[TimeStamp]= e.[TimeStamp] and tb2.maxDate is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if maxDate exists by using coalesce:

```
coalesce(tb2.maxDate, e.[TimeStamp]) -- will return e.[TimeStamp] if tb2.maxDate is null
```